# integrity error when implementing cross join using python flask sqlalchemy orm

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, database-schema

Table ER diagram

[image]

database model

```
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'A'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<A {}>'.format(self.name)

class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'B'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<B {}>'.format(self.name)


class AB(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, index=True, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'), nullable=False, )
    b_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('domain.id'), nullable=False, unique=False)

    a = db.relationship('A', backref=db.backref('A', lazy=True))
    b = db.relationship('B', backref=db.backref('B', lazy=True))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<AB, A{}  B{}>".format(self.a, self.b)
```

CODE TO ADD DATA

```
  l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

import db
for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        x1 = A(name=i)
        x2= B(name=j)

        x3 = AB(a=x1, b=x2)
        db.session.add(x3)
        db.session.commit()
db.session.close()

# HERE db is flask_sqlalchemy object
```

what i want is to create AXB in AB ie (1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4)..,(1,2,1),(1,2,2)..

but i am getting error

> error : sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: a.name

This is just a cross join of table A and table B, but when i trying to do it via python i am getting the intgerity error.

i want to make name in table A and B unique also, is this approach a good one or not tell me and how should i tackle this problem

thanks

Comment: Should this `x1 = A(name=i)` be outside the `j` loop?

Comment: no it can be, but it is not afftecting the AB process, it is something wrong with the creation as mannualy i am able to edit the table but through sqlalechemy orm i am getting the error,  i have tried th approch too